# How to return to code after I'm done with JavaFX scene

Tags: java, javafx

I'm launching my JavaFX scene as:

Applicaiton.launch(Main.class);

form my java code.

How to return to my code after I'm done with JavaFX!

Example:

```
public String Method()
{
  Stirng s = "MyName";
  Application.launch(Main.class);//here I lauch JavaFX scene

  s.trim();//how to come back here after I'm done with that scene.


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Platform.exit(); will do it click [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String...%29) for javafx2.2 documentation

Answer (score 1):

It's not supposed to work that way. You start by extending `javafx.application.Application`, then the entry point is `start(Stage)`, which you must override. That method is the place where you have to set up the `Scene` for your stage, build the layout with `Node`'s (buttons, layout managers, text fields, checkboxes), and register event handlers. You can access startup parameters with `getParameters()`.

The application can be launched by providing the usual `main()` that calls `launch()`, a facility of JavaFX. So the minimal JavaFX application looks like:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    VBox root = new VBox();
    root.getChildren().setAll(new Label("Hello world!"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
    // Add widgets and set up event handlers
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String... args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

Comment: Note you can also override `stop()`. The `stop()` method is called when the application is "finished".